# How to iterate through modules with user input?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I asked this Q few days ago and would appreciated much if you help me. One gentleman pepr has chipped in though. I seem to have run to a brick wall. My code is for a game for children to play with. It is as follows:

```
import re
import sys
name = input
name = input('Please Enter your question: ').lower()
name2 - name[:]
    for item in name2:
    if len(name2) >= 3:
     MODULE1
    elif len(name2) >= 3:
     MODULE2
    elif len(name2) >=3:
     MODULE3............# CONTINUES LIKE THIS FOR THESE MODULES
```

Sample MODULES
MODULE1

```
import re
import sys
name = input
name = input(Please Enter your question: ').lower
name2 = name[:]
colorLists = ['what is my color', 'color', ...]# this list have about 5mb of sample lists.Other lists have items for foods, cars, toys etc
for item in name2:
    if item in name2 and in colorLists:
     print('you found the color here')
     name3 = input('What is your favorite color?')
     if name3 == red:
      print('You are hot!')
     elif name3 == pink:
      print('You must be a lady')
     elif name3 == blue:
      print('Boys love this')
     elif....#continues with as many colors as possible
```

Modules 2,3,4,etc have different games for say cars, homes, foods, toys, etc
So back to the same question above, once I import MODULES, ONLY the first module runs. I want it to work in a way that it will jump to MODULE2 if the question is not in MODULE1.
Once more, am new to Python and your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please actually fix your code first. It contains errors and is not explaining what you are doing. For example what is `MODULE1` supposed to mean?

Comment: poke...am very new to Python and please bear with me on that. Module1(and other modules) is a sample of the many modules I have created for import to the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use functions or classes for the individual games to make them more compact. I give you a quick example:

main.py:

```
import games

GAMES = ('color', 'food', 'car', 'toy')

while True:
    question = input('Please enter your question: ').lower()
    if not question:
        break
    for g in GAMES:             
        if g in question:
            getattr(games, g)()
            break
    else:
        print('I do not have a game for that! :(')

print('Byebye!')
```

games.py:

```
COLORS = {
    'blue': 'Boys love this.',
    'pink': 'You must be a lady.',
    'red': 'You are hot!',
    }

def color():
    print('You found the color here.')
    while True:
        answer = input('What is your favorite color? ').lower()
        if answer in COLORS:
            print(COLORS[answer])
            return
        else:
            print('I don\'t know such a color.')

def food():
    print('Don\'t eat so much!')
```

Sample run:

```
D:\test>python main.py
Please enter your question: what color I like
You found the color here.
What is your favorite color? blue
Boys love this.
Please enter your question: what food I like
Don't eat so much!
Please enter your question: when I was born
I do not have a game for that! :(
Please enter your question:
Byebye!
```

EDIT to answer comment: Import them and put the matching functions to a dictionary. Example:

main.py:

```
import games
import games2
import games3

GAMES = {
    'color': games.color,
    'food': games.food,
    'car': games.car,
    'toy': games.toy,
    'somethingelse': games2.somethingelsefunction,
    }

while True:
    question = input('Please enter your question: ').lower()
    if not question:
        break
    for key, func in GAMES.items():             
        if key in question:
            func()
            break
    else:
        print('I do not have a game for that! :(')

print('Byebye!')
```

Comment: Hey THANK YOU so much for the edit. Now I have some direction!

Comment: Hi, back to you once again. I noted that I have made more modules similar to the one suggested of games. The problem is how do I incorporate them into main like the one above? Thanks i advance

Comment: Thanks. I can see that you only have to import it as a function. What if the module is a simple statement such as print('hello World')? without def FunctionName():...

Comment: It is printed at time of importing immediately.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I have another assignment almost similar that  am stuck, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373361/how-to-import-many-modules-to-main-and-execute