# How to import many modules to main and execute

Tags: python

once again am a newbie to python. I have this assignment that involves searching for details of a certain club by entering the name of a club or asking a keyword such as Arsenal score etc. I have made several modules modules for several teams as follows:

The closest I came to main is this:

```
def main():
    import team que1

if __name__ =='__main__':main()
```

I also have other modules for other teams such as NBA, Hockey,Rugby etc. Every time I run the module separately, it works, but I need a way to import into a main to allow a user to enter any key word such as 'Chicago Bulls players' and the module runs or 'Arsenal score' and the module runs from the main. The modules contain quite a long detail and that is why I have separated the long code into these modules. I have also put them into packages.Please help

Comment: So, do you ve a mapping between the Team name and module name ?

Comment: sorry @yopy i don't understand what that is. Am very new to this

Comment: first of all could you please indent your snippet.

Comment: So, you are trying  to load a module base on the user input right ?

Comment: Yes, and am not sure how to go about that

Comment: I've fixed your indentation as I think you intended it, but please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is small snippet to make you understand:

1. In python you can import module by passing module name as string. [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)
2. two script in my snippet:

2.1 main script name is menu.py.

2.2 module name is arsenal which will load based on your input string:

You can extend the main script and module, the way you like. this is just for understanding.

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def load_module(name):
    return __import__(name)

def what_score(module_name, sc):
    return getattr(module_name, 'score')(sc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Input team name: ",
    team_name = raw_input().strip()
    module_name = load_module(team_name)
    print what_score(module_name, 5)
```

**arsenal.py**

```
def score(n):
    return 'Score from [%s] is %d' % (__name__, n)
```

Output:

```
:tmp:> python menu.py
Input team name:  arsenal
Score from [arsenal] is 5
:tmp:>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the great input. Most surely appreciated

Comment: sure, we can extend the team by maintaining a dictionary to filter wrong input from users.

Comment: So, module name couldn't be with space, so you need to map to a string without space using dictionary, like if a person use d = {'Aston Villa' : 'Aston_Villa' }

Comment: got it, thanks module_name = load_module = { Arsenal, Aston_Villa, Cardiff....} ?

Comment: Yes, what ever the user input, convert into one string because python module should be one string without space, once you converted you can load the module and the converted string should be same as module name. For example, if use input `Aston Villa` you need to convert into `Aston_Villa` and you should ve module name `Aston_Villa.py` some where in your package.